# select product quantity when other product options are changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select the quantity value when the product options are changed.  I've tried various jquery functions but I'm getting nowhere fast.  I also have to think about multiple products being updated.  I need to select the quantity so when the options are changed all the options/quantities are passed to the backend.

Can anyone help with this?

Here is a 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8ws5mty/2/) showing my html/jquery.

I thought maybe I could iterate over each of the `.qty` classes and find the `.list .qty` `<select>` element but I'm not having much luck.

```
$(".qty").each(function()
{
 // var name = $(this).attr('name');
 // console.log(name);
//var x=$('.list').closest('select').find(':selected').val(); //find the value
var x=$('.qty').siblings('.list'); //find the value
console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output that you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.list select` to grab each select list:

```
$('.list select').each(function()
{
    $(this).find('option').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).val(), $(this).text());
    }); //find the value


});
```

For just the value of the select with class `qty`, use can simply use:

```
var qty = $('select.qty option:selected').val();

console.log(qty);
```